# How to load data to an FFmpeg - AVBuffer

Tags: c, ffmpeg, buffer

I'm working on an FFmpeg project that I want to load the pieces of the video manually, without using the `av_read_frame(...)` to get the `AVPacket`s. I found the `AVBufferRef` struct but I don't know the way to load the chunk file into that.

Do you have any tips or help?

UPDATE:
The current code is above:

```
main(){
    byte* buffer_data;  
    // (...) buffer_data <- 'h.264 file' - b-frame loaded from disk.

    AVBufferRef* pAVBuf = (AVBufferRef*)buffer_data;
    AVPacket pkt_demo;

    int r = av_packet_from_data(&pkt_demo, buffer_data, lSize);
    //or pkt_demo.buf = pAVBuf; ? 

    decode(codec_ctx, frame, &pkt_demo, fout);
    av_packet_unref(pkt);
}


void decode(AVCodecContext* dec_ctx, AVFrame* frame, AVPacket* pkt, FILE* f)
{
    int ret;

    //send packet to decoder
    ret = avcodec_send_packet(dec_ctx, pkt);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error sending a packet for decoding\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    while (ret >= 0) {
        
        // receive frame from decoder
        // we may receive multiple frames or we may consume all data from decoder, then return to main loop
        ret = avcodec_receive_frame(dec_ctx, frame);
        if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF) {
            printf("i'm on it\n");
            return;
        }
        else if (ret < 0) {
            // something wrong, quit program
            fprintf(stderr, "Error during decoding\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("saving frame %3d\n", dec_ctx->frame_number);
        fflush(stdout);


        // display frame on sdl window
        displayFrame(frame, dec_ctx);

        // send frame info to writing function
        pgm_save(frame->data[0], frame->linesize[0], frame->width, frame->height, f);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: In what form is your _chunk file_ when it is to be _loaded_ into the `AVBufferRef`?

Comment: every file is i or b frame (h.264 video encoding)

Comment: Without using `av_read_frame()`, you would have to open the binary file and write your own binary parser to extract single frames of binary data into a `byte` array, created eg.  as `byte *pData = malloc(sizeof(AVBufferRef));` Once you have a single `byte` array read into that buffer, then the struct instance can be _loaded_ with that data using `AVBufferRef *pAVBuf = (AVBufferRef *)pData;  But because of the nature of the `struct` variable type, with padding alignment issues, this would _only_ work all of these steps were done in the same environment, on the same machine.

Comment: ...Of course because `av_read_frame(...)` already does all of this, and does it in a safe and validated way, it begs the question _why would you ever choose to do it manually?_

Comment: The main idea is to play real-time video from a drone via kafka. Any message from kafka has a frame (h264) so, for that way, I need to set the ```AVPacket```s manually. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I just laid out a method that will do that for you.  Beyond this, please show what you have already tried, and why it is not working for you.  ( [mcve] ).

Comment: I just updated the question with my code. I suggest, the problem is the main function. decode function is checked.

Comment: Dimitris - Adding your code snippet helps to see the problem.  But, when  commenting to a particular user, prepend the user name with `@` eg: `@ryyker`.  so they will be flagged.  I just happened to check back and saw that you had edited :)  (Using the `@` is not necessary when the comment is placed under user's own post.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function:

```
 int av_packet_from_data (AVPacket *pkt, uint8_t *data, int size)
```

Initializes a reference-counted packet from ***av_malloc()ed*** `data`.

But in your code snippet, the buffer passed to this function does not yet point to memory, it is simply declared...

```
byte* buffer_data;  
// (...) buffer_data <- 'h.264 file' - b-frame loaded from disk.
```

Also, according to the documentation for [av_packet_from_data()](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.7/group__lavc__packet.html#ga7ca877e1f0ded89a27199b65e9a077dc), the buffer should be created as `uint_t *` to prevent warning from your compiler.

Change this:

```
byte* buffer_data;
```

To This:

```
size_t buffer_size = 4096;
uint8_t *buffer_data = av_malloc(buffer_size);
if (!buffer_data) {
    //handle error
}
 AVPacket pkt_demo;
....
int r = av_packet_from_data(&pkt_demo, buffer_data, buffer_size);
```

There may be other issues in your code, but this addresses creating and using the buffer correctly.  (There is [sample code here](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.7/avio_reading_8c-example.html#a20) illustrating a full example of the section I have shown above.)